# Current running queries in Google Bigquery via system tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is there any system tables in Google Bigquery to check all the current running queries? I am looking similar to V$SQL table and v$Session tables in Oracle.

Answer (score 9):

You can query the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs) view to retrieve real-time metadata about BigQuery jobs. This view contains currently running jobs, as well as the last 180 days of history of completed jobs.

for example

```
SELECT
 job_id,
 creation_time,
 query
FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER
WHERE state != "DONE"
```

Note: Valid states include PENDING, RUNNING, and DONE.

Comment: Note that this will only return the jobs for your current user. You may want `JOBS_BY_PROJECT` instead. See: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs