# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSIONS_BY_USER returns 0 rows

Tags: session, google-bigquery, information-schema

I am running this

`select session_id, user_email, project_id, creation_time FROM` region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSIONS_BY_PROJECT WHERE is_active = true AND  creation_time >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);`

The query returns 0 rows which I was not expecting. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-sessions-by-user) says the view holds session information for the last 180 days.

Is there a configuration change I need to make in the project to query this view?

thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not what I thought it was. I was thinking it would give sp_who2 type information like in sql server but it is not. I'll keep looking for the information I need.

Comment: Looks like I need something like this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62361487/current-running-queries-in-google-bigquery-via-system-tables

SELECT
 job_id,
 creation_time,
 query
FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER
WHERE state != "DONE"